# URI exception raised when working with Metro and Images

Tags: c#, uri, visual-studio-2012

I am working on a Metro UI app for Windows 8, and I am trying to retrieve an image from the project folder.

Here is my initial code:

```
public static Image GetImage(string path, int width, int height, int margin)
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Width = width;
        img.Height = height;
        img.Margin = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Thickness(margin);

        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.Absolute));

        img.Source = bi;

        return img;
    }
```

And the method call:

```
Image = Extension.GetImage("Classe;component/Images/faq.png", 100, 100, 0);
```

And the Error:

```
Exception:Thrown: "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined." (System.UriFormatException)
A System.UriFormatException was thrown: "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."
```

If I change the URI kind to relative:

```
Exception:Thrown: "The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215849 for details." (System.ArgumentException)
A System.ArgumentException was thrown: "The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215849 for details."
```

Image Path is Images/faq.png.  Set to Content and Copy Always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for Windows.Foundation.Uri, it looks like WinRT doesn't support relative URIs. MS invented yet another URI format for WinRT resources.

Try something like this and see if it works:

```
new Uri("Classe://MyAssembly/component/Images/faq.png")
```

Note: YOU DON'T add your actual assembly name -- the MyAssembly part IS LITERAL TEXT.

Comment: In the question, I already stated that if you change to URIKind.Relative: If I change the URI kind to relative:

Exception:Thrown: "The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215849 for details." (System.ArgumentException)
A System.ArgumentException was thrown: "The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215849 for details."

Comment: Judging from the documentation for Windows.Foundation.Uri, it looks like WinRT doesn't support relative URIs. 

MS invented yet another URI format for WinRT resources. Try something like this and see if it works:

new Uri("ms-resource://MyAssembly/component/Images/faq.png")
Note that you don't add your actual assembly name -- the MyAssembly part is literal text.

Comment: Fascinating, it's odd Microsoft makes so many standards like this :( I hope when they release the full version of .NET 4.5/5 and VS2012 they bring back UriKind.Relative to work with WinRT.

I might as well mark this answer as the question, please put the new Uri("Classe://MyAssembly/component/Images/faq.png") in your edited answer. Thanks.